# Secure individual pages with asp.net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using the asp.net membership and role provider tools and can't figure out how to require login for specific pages. I tried putting the pages in a seperate directory and adding this to my web.config but it still denies access after succesful login.

```
<location path="Purchase">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
     <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Your Purchase location denies access to all users.

Comment: Did my response not answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

'*' refers to all users (logged in or otherwise). If you want to refer only to users who are not authenticated (not logged in), use '?'.